# Test to see if individuals are distinguishable

Tags: r, regression

I conducted some experiments where I modified two variables (var 1 and var 2), and measured an outcome variable (yield). For each combination of var 1 and var 2, I assigned a TestNumber. Some combinations of var 1 and var 2 were tested with a single individual (such as TestNumber 9 in the figure), some were tested with two individuals (such as TestNumber 6 in the figure), and others were tested with three individuals (such as TestNumber 1 in the figure).

I'd like to determine if there is any systematic difference between the three individuals (orange, purple, and black), so that I can know if I can pool their results together for downstream analyses. But I want to take into account the fact that some TestNumbers generally performed better than others.

I've done linear regression, trying to predict the yield using the individual as the predictor variable:

```
Call:
lm(formula = exampleData$Yield ~ exampleData$individual)
 Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -0.56544 -0.19684  0.03037  0.23367  0.39646 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   0.58854    0.05335  11.031   <2e-16 ***
exampleData$individualorange  0.11139    0.07627   1.460    0.149    
exampleData$individualpurple  0.08079    0.07399   1.092    0.279    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2614 on 70 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03184,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.004178 
F-statistic: 1.151 on 2 and 70 DF,  p-value: 0.3222
```

However, I don't think that's good enough, because it ignores the information from var1 and var2--one of the individuals might be present at a higher frequency in the higher TestNumbers, which have a higher yield.

If I try `summary(lm(exampleData$Yield ~ exampleData$var1 + exampleData$var2 + exampleData$individual))` then I also get a large p-value for the slope on exampleData$individual, but is that sufficient to determine that the three individuals are not distinguishable?

Any pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks very much!

[image]

**Data**

```
individual condition var1 var2 Yield
black      1         10   15   0.2131
purple     1         10   15   0.3189
orange     1         10   15   0.9993
purple     2         12   15   0.1667
orange     2         12   15   0.2423
black      2         12   15   0.1462
purple     3         13   15   0.1876
black      3         13   15   0.2297
black      4         18   15   0.8693
purple     4         18   15   0.6991
orange     5         25   15   0.804
black      5         25   15   0.2084
purple     5         25   15   0.9396
black      6         30   15   0.0231
purple     6         30   15   0.5337
orange     7         10   45   0.4939
orange     8         12   45   0.446
orange     9         13   45   0.7962
black     10         15   45   0.6812
purple    10         15   45   0.5147
orange    10         15   45   0.439
black     11         17   45   0.2627
purple    11         17   45   0.4074
orange    11         17   45   0.9948
black     12         20   45   0.9716
purple    12         20   45   0.8603
orange    12         20   45   0.9434
black     13         26   45   0.6757
purple    13         26   45   0.8618
black     14         28   45   0.3611
purple    14         28   45   0.7874
orange    14         28   45   0.2899
black     15         30   45   0.5435
purple    15         30   45   0.4882
black     16         34   45   0.5456
purple    16         34   45   0.491
orange    16         34   45   0.619
purple    17         45   45   0.698
black     17         45   45   0.3917
orange    17         45   45   0.9568
black     18         50   45   0.9163
purple    18         50   45   0.3317
purple    19         55   45   0.8703
orange    20         56   45   0.4262
black     20         56   45   0.4751
black     21         59   45   0.6788
purple    21         59   45   0.9172
orange    21         59   45   0.5628
orange    22         65   45   0.9585
purple    22         65   45   0.9056
black     22         65   45   0.9022
orange    23         10   90   0.8286
purple    23         10   90   0.703
black     23         10   90   0.8413
orange    24         15   90   0.9259
purple    24         15   90   0.903
black     24         15   90   0.5991
orange    25         20   90   0.7303
purple    25         20   90   0.5813
black     26         21   90   0.9131
orange    26         21   90   0.7542
purple    26         21   90   0.9896
orange    27         28   90   0.5668
purple    27         28   90   0.8928
purple    28         30   90   0.8766
orange    29         35   90   0.6794
black     30         41   90   0.8845
black     31         45   90   0.8067
orange    31         45   90   0.6489
purple    32         46   90   0.6454
black     32         48   90   0.985
orange    32         48   90   0.9922
purple    33         50   90   0.8317
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify these now? Are "orange", "purple" &"black" the names of the only 3 individuals who took part in the study? What would it mean to be able to "distinguish" between the individuals? Do you want to know if they differ in mean yield, or if you can predict which individual is which from knowing `var1`, `var2` & `yield`? Is "TestNumber" the same as `condition`? Does `condition` just indicate a unique combination of values?

Comment: Yes, TestNumber is the same as condition, and they are both just a unique combination of values from var1 and var2.

Orange, purple, and black are the names of 3 individuals who were evaluated in the study. My main concern is I want to regress var1 and var2 against Yield, but I'm not sure if I can just use all three individuals and ignore the fact that they are different individuals, or if I have to treat them separately.

Comment: I think that is similar, if not identical, to being able to determine which individual is which from knowing `var1`, `var2`, and `yield`?